# Cell text is not displayed using easytable and fpdf, PHP 7.4

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, php-7.4

Using the easytable library (https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable), the PDF is generated correctly with content containing special characters in the development environment. However, in the production environment, with the same PHP version (7.4) and all files synchronized, strings with special characters are not displayed at all. The cell is left empty. To display the data correctly, `utf8_decode($string)` was used. With this formatting, special characters are displayed normally with standard FPDF methods, as shown in:

```
$pdf = new exFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->Write(6, utf8_decode('açãó'));
$pdf->Output();
```

When using the easyfpdf library, the error occurs even when the string value is handled:

```
$pdf = new exFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

$table = new easyTable($pdf, 3, 'border:1;font-size:12;');
$table->easyCell(utf8_decode('açãó'), 'valign:T; bgcolor:#eee6ff;');
$table->printRow();
$table->endTable(4);

$pdf->Output();
```